# Exception in Application Construction - Java

Tags: java, exception, javafx, event-handling

While working on trying to make some simple buttons with Event Driven Programming I was looking at an example in my textbook (Intro to Java Programming 10th edi.) I followed some code from the book to try and replicate it myself for a project I'm working on. The program compiles, but when it runs I get:

```
    Exception in Application constructor
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to construct Application instance: class ButtonPackage.ButtonEvent
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:907)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$156(LauncherImpl.java:182)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: ButtonPackage.ButtonEvent.<init>()
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1825)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:818)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$176(PlatformImpl.java:326)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$174(PlatformImpl.java:295)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$175(PlatformImpl.java:294)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$149(WinApplication.java:191)
        ... 1 more
```

After getting advice from the answers I was able to get it working. Below is the corrected condensed code:

```
    package ButtonPackage;
    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.geometry.Pos;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.control.Button;
    import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;
    import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
    import javafx.event.EventHandler;

    /**
     * Created by Brandon on 12/5/2015.
     */
    public class ButtonEvent extends Application {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Application.launch(args);
        }

        @Override //Override start method Application Class
        public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
            //create pane set properties
            HBox pane = new HBox(10);
            pane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
            Button btEnter = new Button("ENTER NUMBER");
            Button btCheck = new Button("CHECK IF WINNER");
            EnterNumber handler1 = new EnterNumber();
            btEnter.setOnAction(handler1);
            CheckWinner handler2 = new CheckWinner();
            btCheck.setOnAction(handler2);
            pane.getChildren().addAll(btEnter, btCheck);

            //Create scene place on stage
            Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
            primaryStage.setTitle("HandleEvent"); //Set Stage Title
            primaryStage.setScene(scene); //Place scene in stage
            primaryStage.show(); //Display stage
        }//end start
    }//end ButtonEvent

    class EnterNumber implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("ENTER NUMBER button clicked");
        }//end handle
    }//end EnterNumber

    class CheckWinner implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("CHECK IF WINNER button clicked");
            //eventLottery.main();
        }//end handle
    }//end CheckWinner
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are running this in IntelliJ. While it is permissible for an `Application` subclass not to have a `main(...)` method, not all IDEs support this execution mode.

Note that, in any execution mode, your main class **must** be `public`.

If you want to run from inside the IDE, add a main method that simply calls [`launch()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html#launch-java.lang.String...-):

```
public class ButtonEvent extends Application {

    // existing code ...

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

(or just run it directly from the command line).

Comment: I put the main right after the ButtonEvent class and tried it at the end of the class, but it's still throwing the Application Exception (the error message is longer, but seems to be the same thing) Would Eclipse be able to handle it or should I just use the command line? I really like Intellij xD

Comment: "The error message is longer"... so it's **not** the same? Please [edit the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34121253/edit) to include the new error message.

Comment: Updated the main post to include error message and my code changes.

Comment: You also need to make the main class `public`. See update. Note, of course, this means it must be defined in a file called `ButtonEvent.java`.

Comment: Thanks! Updating the main post to show the correct code. You saved me!

Answer (score 0):

You did not define a `public static main(String[] args)` method.  You need to define this method, and tell java which class this method is in.

Comment: You do not need a `main` method for an `Application` subclass in Java 8, if you are running with the standard Oracle JRE. However, not all IDEs are aware of or support this execution mode.